# virtual vs dedicated server?

Tags: vps, web-hosting

What is the biggest difference between virtual and dedicated server?

Answer (score 2):

In what context?

From the PoV of a data-centre manager, VMs allow better usage of hardware, and more efficient power consumption.

VMs allow you to quickly spool up additional resources to handle more load. Often, VMs do not have the same tight integration with hardware as bare metal boxes... particularly where certain database raw-device drivers are concerned.

VMs allow better segmentation of functionality... you could have a VM with your web frontend, another with the business logic (JEE or whatever) and a third with the database backend. This would provide greater flexibility, in that migration of servers is much easier than if the OS was installed on a hardware server.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's a right answer to this question, but mine would be with a Virtual Server, you are competing with others for use of the hardware. A dedicated server means your CPU time and memory is your CPU time and memory.

Answer (score 0):

The biggest difference is cost.

Take a look [here](http://znetindia.com/vps-hosting?a_aid=4ca253fbf2366)
and [here](http://znetindia.com/dedicated-hosting?a_aid=4ca253fbf2366).

VPS costs about 3000INR/Month whereas dedicated starts from about 10000INR/Month

Sure in dedicated server you will get more space and memory but what if 40GB space is sufficient and you don't need 250 GB hard drive? Then you must choose VPS.